# In Django Rest Framework (DRF) how to do pagination when we are getting page number from request body?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

Generally, when we use pagination in Django Rest Framework (DRF), from URL we are sending parameters like `some-url/?page=2&page_size=50`

Now, in my case, I'm sending a request with those parameters being sent from the request with the below payload.

```
pagination : {
    "page": 2,
    "page_size": 50
}
```

How to get this paginated when a request is made with any page number?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you want to achieve.